# how to look up object type of Object['key'] in second parameter function when 'key' is the first function parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class that I use to create "vault" classes. Those vaults use `enum`s to define public members:

```
export abstract class Vault<EnumKeyVault extends string, ObjectsForVault> {
...
}
```

And I use it in this way:

```
interface SomeObject {
 prop1: boolean,
 prop2: string
}


enum MyEnum {
  Key1: 'Key1',
  Key2: 'Key2'
}

class MyVault extends Vault<MyEnum, SomeObject> {
  constructor(){
   super(
     [MyEnum.Key1]: {
        prop1: true,
        prop2: 'I am Key 1'
     },
     [MyEnum.Key2]: {
        prop1: false,
        prop2: 'I am Key 2'
     },
   );
  }
}

const myVault = new MyVault();
myVault.Key1; 
myVault.Key2;
```

I want to define a generic function in `Vault` that allows me to find a Vault member by the value of one of the member object properties.

Something like:

```
const myVault = new MyVault();

myVault.findByMemberKey('prop2', 'I Am Key 2') // Should return myVault.Key2
```

I am having problem finding how to define the type of the second parameter, since I want that typescript can infer that if I use `prop2` it should be of type `string` and other types should be not accepted.

```
public findByMemberKey(key: keyof ObjectsForVault, value: WHAT_SHOULD_I_WRITE_HERE?) { }
```

Pd: Sorry I was not sure how to write the title...

Comment: ```findByMember<T extends keyof ObjectsForVault>(key: T, value: ObjectsForVault[T])```

Comment: @НиколайГольцев perfect! care to do an answer so I can select it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interface keys are unique and signature of `findByMember` contains it as argument, you can use TS feature called indexed property access in conjunction with generic type to be able lock any kind information within value type of specific key including whole value type itself.

That's how you can do this:

```
findByMember<T extends keyof ObjectsForVault>(key: T, value: ObjectsForVault[T])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this using conditional types

```
enum MyEnum {
  Key1 = 'Key1',
  Key2 = 'Key2'
}

type Conditional<T extends MyEnum> = T extends MyEnum.Key2 ? string : never

function fn<T extends MyEnum>(a: T, b: Conditional<T>) {}

fn(MyEnum.Key2, "foo")
// fn(MyEnum.Key2, 3) error
```

Comment: This would not escalate, I have several `vaults` with different enums. It hast to be generic